# Combining sed statements

Tags: sed

Let's say my input file looks like:

```
ID1
1    5
6    8
ID2
1    4
5    7
```

I'm trying to formulate a loop that can combine these actions:

- If the line begins with a letter: keep the '\ n' after the field
- If the line begins with a number: replace every '\ t' and '\ n' with a comma ( `sed 's / \ t /, / g; s / \ n /, / g '` ) EXCEPT if the next line begins with a letter ( `sed 's / \ t /, / g'` )

Expected output:

```
ID1     
1, 5, 6, 8
ID2     
1, 4, 5, 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '/^[0-9]/{:a;s/[\t\n ]\+/,/g;N;/\n[A-Z]/!ba;}'
```

will do the stuff.

Explanation:

`/^[0-9]/` will match only to lines started with number and apply command group to it

`{}` command group to apply

`{:a;s/[\t\n ]\+/,/g;N;/\n[A-Z]/!ba;}` will read in cycle line by line and replace all spaces, tabs and newlines to comma until line started with letter.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because you proposed a sed method, but @fedorqui's answer using awk works perfectly as well!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that as follows: if the current line starts with a digit, append the next line into pattern space and then replace sequences of spaces, tabs and newlines with comma-space:

```
$ sed '/^[0-9]/{N;s/[ \t\n]\+/, /g}' file
ID1
1, 5, 6, 8
ID2
1, 4, 5, 7
```

Comment: Note that it will not work if OP has 3 or more lines with numbers. If it's just like in example, then it's fine.

Comment: @rush - yeah, mine too, I think. I should probably fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for `awk`, that provides more control and generalizes the problem:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=","}
      /^[^A-Z]/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (!a) a=$i; else a=a OFS $i} next}
      {if (a) print a; a=""; print}
     END{print a}'
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=","}` set input field separator as tab and output field separator as comma.
- `/^[^A-Z]/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (!a) a=$i; else a=a OFS $i} next}` on lines not starting with capital letter, store the values in a variable `a`.
- `{if (a) print a; a=""; print}` in the rest of the cases (that is, lines starting with capital letter), print the stored value together with current line.
- `END{print a}` after processing the whole file, print the last stored variable with the values from the last block.

See output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=","}/^[^A-Z]/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (!a) a=$i; else a=a OFS $i} next} {if (a) print a; a=""; print} END{print a}' file
ID1
1,5,6,8
ID2
1,4,5,7
```

---

In sed, remember you can always use the `-e` option to combine commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -s '\t\nI' '  \n' <<\DATA |\
sed 's/^/I/;s/  */\n/;s/  *[0-9]/,&/g'
ID1
1    5
6    8
ID2
1    4
5    7
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
ID1
1, 5, 6, 8
ID2
1, 4, 5, 7
```

- First `tr` translates all tabs and newlines into spaces *and* all capital Is into newlines. It also squeezes repeats. That makes it really easy because at this point it passes to `sed` input that looks like:

  `^D [num] [num] [num] [num] [num] ... [num] $`
- Next `sed` puts the *I* back, substitutes a newline for the first space on the line, cleans up any trailing spaces, then...
- Sticks a comma in front of every space remaining on the line and it's done.